# What is meant by Runtime of VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am totally confused with the ability of VS Code.  at one end it says supported runtime is nodejs and asp.net 5 and at other end it says it supports objective-c, php, ruby.

I am not clear. Can anyone please explain ?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Everything is explained here: 
https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/overview
and here: 
https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/runtimes/nodejs

Objective-c, Php, Ruby, VisualBasic.NET, etc. have only syntax highlighting and maybe some snippets and intelli sense. But you have no ability to debug them in Visual Studio Code.

The runtime means that you are able to run and debug applications in Visual Studio Code. You have support for Javascipt and Typescript via NodeJs and for C# via the ASP.NET5 runtime.